# regex for zip-code

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

I need Regex which can satisfy all my three condtions for zip-code.  E.g-

1. 12345
2. 12345-6789
3. 12345 1234

Any pointers and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: The duplicate closure looks sketchy - the dupe is asking for a regex that will match any postal code from any nation ever, whereas this question is asking for a regex to match zip codes, which are a US-only thing, which makes this question much narrower in scope than the dupe - but there *is* in fact an answer to be found at the dupe. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7185241/1709587 which lists the Unicode CLDR's (old, now deprecated, but probably still adequate in many cases) postal code regexes for >100 countries, including the US. The US regex is `\d{5}([ \-]\d{4})?`.

Comment: I want to point out that in the world there are zip codes that do not respect just those 3 rules. For example, Dublin zip codes are D01, D02, etc. Or the zip code for Manama is 323. Also, other cities like Hong Kong don't have zip codes.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

```
^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$
```

- `^` = Start of the string.
- `\d{5}` = Match 5 digits (for condition 1, 2, 3)
- `(?:…)` = Grouping
- `[-\s]` = Match a space (for condition 3) or a hyphen (for condition 2)
- `\d{4}` = Match 4 digits (for condition 2, 3)
- `…?` = The pattern before it is optional (for condition 1)
- `$` = End of the string.

Comment: `\s` will match any whitespace, including tabs and new lines.

Comment: Hi what about the condition 123451234 without space

Comment: @ProVega: Reading the comments on the (now deleted) answer you linked to, that appears to be incorrect. For example, `00544` is a valid zip code; `544` is not.

Comment: @AjaySuwalka: All you would have to do to accommodate for 123451234 with no space is place a ? after [-\s], so it would become:

^\d{5}(?:[-\s]?\d{4})?$

Comment: in Javascript I put it this way:                                                                 var zipPattern = /\d{5}(?:[-]\d{4})?/;
            if (!zipPattern.test($scope.data.MailingZip)) {
                $scope.errMsgZip = true;
                validForm = false;
            }                                                                                                       However, it allows 12345-4. Shouldn't this be invalid? the last part should be either 4 digits or 0.

Comment: A little late to the party, and maybe not the prettiest bell at the ball, but I've added additional optional spaces on either side of the hyphen - mostly for aesthetics. `/(^\d{5}(?:[\s]?[-\s][\s]?\d{4})?$)/`

Comment: `/^\d{5}((?:[-\s]\d{4})|(\d{4}))?$/`  - for formats 12345-6789, 123456789, 12345

Comment: A better way to allow for spaces around the hyphen is to just use: `[-\s]+` inside the (?...) block. Or if it would be an option to have no separator between the digits, then you could use `[-\s]*`  I also like to match the first two digits separately to identify the state, so I expand out the first digits: `/^(\d\d)(\d\d\d)(?:[-\s]*\d{4})?$/`.

Comment: This regex `^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$` in the answer doesn't consider 57401-57402. I don't know if anyone verified that.

Answer (score 7):

For the listed three conditions only, these expressions might work also:

```
^\d{5}[-\s]?(?:\d{4})?$
^\[0-9]{5}[-\s]?(?:[0-9]{4})?$
^\[0-9]{5}[-\s]?(?:\d{4})?$
^\d{5}[-\s]?(?:[0-9]{4})?$
```

#### [Please see this demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/O6xGdR/1/)

If we would have had unexpected additional spaces in between 5 and 4 digits or a continuous 9 digits zip code, such as:

```
123451234
12345 1234
12345  1234
```

this expression for instance would be a secondary option with less constraints:

```
^\d{5}([-]|\s*)?(\d{4})?$
```

#### [Please see this demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/CUsElL/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^\d{5}[-\s]?(?:\d{4})?$/gm;
const str = `12345
12345-6789
12345 1234
123451234
12345 1234
12345  1234
1234512341
123451`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be obvious for most people who use RegEx frequently, but in case any readers are new to RegEx, I thought I should point out an observation I made that was helpful for one of my projects.

In a previous answer from @kennytm:

```
^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$
```

> …? = The pattern before it is optional (for condition 1)

If you want to allow both standard 5 digit and +4 zip codes, this is a great example.

To match only zip codes in the US 'Zip + 4' format as I needed to do (conditions 2 and 3 only), simply remove the last `?` so it will always match the last 5 character group.

A useful tool I recommend for tinkering with RegEx is linked below:

https://regexr.com/

I use this tool frequently when I find RegEx that does something similar to what I need, but could be tailored a bit better.  It also has a nifty RegEx reference menu and informative interface that keeps you aware of how your changes impact the matches for the sample text you entered.

If I got anything wrong or missed an important piece of information, please correct me.

Comment: or you can refer this regex tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uCHRyK_VMo

Answer (score 0):

A minor clarification - the first and second groups of numbers in a U.S. ZIP code cannot contain only zeros. If you want to use a stricter restriction to avoid zeros, here is the corresponding regular expression:

```
^(?!00000)\d{5}(?:[-\s](?!0000)\d{4})?$
```