# Regular Expression for US and other format zip

Tags: regex, groovy

Am working on regular expression for following formats of zip in groovy

```
Includes a letter (L12345)
Includes a dash plus 4 more numbers (77056-1234)
Includes spaces (77056 1234)
```

I have this "^\d{5}(-\d{4})?\$" but its not matching the required formats. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$
```

- `^` = Start of the string.
- `\d{5}` = Match 5 digits (for condition 1, 2, 3)
- `(?:…)` = Grouping
- `[-\s]` = Match a space (for condition 3) or a hyphen (for condition 2)
- `\d{4}` = Match 4 digits (for condition 2, 3)
- `…?` = The pattern before it is optional (for condition 1)
- `$` = End of the string.

This is from the following question, hope it helps

[regex for zip-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577236/regex-for-zip-code)

For the optiona startingil letter use

```
[A-Z]?
```

to make the letter optional. `{1}` is redundant. (Of course you could also write `[A-Z]{0,1}` which would mean the same, but that's what the `?` is there for.)

I think it should go after the `^` but haven't had a chance to test

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply, I think this expression doesn't satisfy the 1st format "L12345"