# Regex validation for ZIP codes for each state

Tags: regex

I'm quite new to regex and trying to write a regular expression that matches the ZIP codes in each state, but having a hard time. As an example, Alaska has ZIP codes between 99501 and 99950, but this doesn't work:

```
99(5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)
```

because it also matches 99951. Anyone done this already, or mind helping me out with at least the pattern for this? Here are the ZIP code ranges for each state:
http://www.structnet.com/instructions/zip_min_max_by_state.html

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577236/regex-for-zip-code

Comment: I'm not good enough with regexp's to give you an answer, but it sounds like you could use lookahead's to solve your problem.  [reference here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) It will proably be a huge pain to write as many of these as you'll need. You may have better luck finding an api to validate the zipcodes for you.

Comment: @MikeN: an API .. or a simple numerical comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

Comment: @Brian: you can also test your RegEx [here](http://regexpal.com). I use this site to refine the regex and prevent unwanted matches. They also provide a (short) summary of the most important keywords (e.g. \d to match any digit)

Comment: @Jongware hmmmm, I'm not sure a 'simple numerical comparison' can help when you have to take state codes <string> into account, then considering states add zipcodes as populations change, I don't think OP will want to always be watching for things like that so he can redeploy his solution. By using a maintained API he does not have to worry about these factors.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the ultimate postal code and ZIP question, since I'm not trying to validate any ZIP code, but rather match a specific range.

As for using an API, I'm doing this through the GUI of a custom CMS, and don't have the option to use any method besides regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp is a poor choice for that problem but I think this one might get the job done:

```
99(5(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[6-8]\d\d|9([0-4]\d|50))
```

http://rubular.com/r/Fs9bTpgGTT