# Check if postal code from form is in range

Tags: html, forms

I ave a question, I've builded an form in HTML. It has an input field called postal code. Now I want the form to check if the postal code entered in that field is in range before submitting.

So if the postcalcode isn't in range it won't submit and notices the user the postal code isn't in range. What's the best way to do that?

This is my input field code

```
<div class="field-element ">
 <input type="text" name="MERGE4" id="MERGE4" placeholder="Postcode *" class="shortnice form-input required"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will do like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Postal code</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>          
            <input id="the_right_way" class="zipcode" type="text" value = "" pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

If user enter invalid postal code, when user press `Submit` button, browser will notice error.

Learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577239/3728901

Comment: Can U make an better example for me? 
I'm only wanting the following postal codes to be accepted:

1011, 1012, 1013, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1021, 1022, 1031, 1032, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1091, 1092, 1092, 1093

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo You will use `pattern="^\10[0-9]{2}$"`, for interactive example: http://regexr.com/3alb0

Comment: Thnx! How can I make my form show an error if it won't match?

Comment: When user enter an invalid value, for random example `ag3dd34`, then press `Submit` button, **browser will warn the error** for user (You don't need do anymore).

Comment: Allright! I tested it, but still have a problem. I keep getting the message that my pattern is invalid.....