# Regex that can contain alphanumeric characters but cannot contain anything other than | , - and space

Tags: java, regex, string

When validating a zip code, I'm trying to check if the zip code that can contain alphanumeric and only the characters `-`, `|` and   (space).

I'm checking

```
"34343-1232".matches("(?!|| |-|[0-9])"))
```

but this doesn't work. Is there an optimum way to do this?

Comment: Are you including `{` and `}` or is that just the formatting of the question?

Comment: Why did you make a *negative* look-ahead?

Comment: Regex matching text containing only digits, dash, and space characters: `matches("[0-9 -]*")`. The dash must be last, so it isn't part of a character range like the `0-9`.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness It's just formatting the question. I'm not including it in the regex

Comment: This question has already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577239/9698608

Comment: @Andreas This works , whatever you gave, but it's not considering the pipe. Should I add pipe anywhere in the expression or is there a sequence to this? Thank you. I want to match |  and - and space

Comment: @UnbearableLightness No, it's not a duplicate. I need pipe and a space and a - . This maybe a zip but a clear picture is what I couldn't find in other posts. I've really looked out for explanation. Great to see all your answers. I just want to understand this concept

Comment: @Ronald Just add the pipe, it's not special inside a character class. Of the characters you need to match, only `-` is special, which is why it needs to be last or be escaped: `matches("[0-9 |-]*")` *(dash last)* or `matches("[0-9\\-| ]*")` *(dash escaped)*

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact zip rules in your country, but this snippet will get you started:

```
// define the pattern - should be defined as class field
// instead of + you could use {3,5} to match min. 3, max. 5 characters - see regular expressions manual
private static final Pattern PATTERN_ZIP = Pattern.compile("^[0-9A-Z]+[ \\-\\|]?[0-9A-Z]+$");

String zip = "1A2-3B4C5";
// Optional: let's make some text cleaning
String cleanZip = zip.toUpperCase().trim();

// Do the mat(c)h
Matcher m = PATTERN_ZIP.matcher(cleanZip);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Zip code correct");
} else {
    System.out.println("Zip code incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the contributing answer. For your reference, it's often best to begin or end character classes with `-`when you want to end with hyphen. This both makes it clear that you're looking for a hyphen (when coming back to the regex) and avoids having to escape or double-escape. I prefer to begin classes with `-`. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing for simple zip codes (e.g. 12345) and enforcing that if an accepted separator (space, comma, pipe) is found it must be trailed by four digits, this regex should suffice.

```
[0-9]{5}(?:[-,| ][0-9]{4})?
```

Comment: Given the limited question, only one example and brief explanation of data, this is the best answer on this page.

Comment: It's correct (assuming fixed number of digits) but could be improved by making the group non capturing `(?:)`. No grouping is required here.

Comment: Neat, +1. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need negative lookahead, you can use a character class (`[]`) instead of the `|` operators, and you'd want to use `^` and `$` to denote the start and end of the string. Like this:

```
"34343-1232".matches("^[0-9| -]+$")
```

Comment: This won't allow for spaces though.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is now something like *34343  multiplespaces  1232* will be matched. Not sure if OP would want that to match.

Comment: Don't need `^` and `$` when using `matches()`.

Comment: Yes I would want to do that match. Great answer. Its really helpful

Comment: @Ronald The formatting on my comment was not rendered. I am not sure this is what you want, check [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/t0SHfh/1).

Comment: Multiple spaces are allowed in the string. Is this what you are after? Same goes for the other delimiters of course.

Comment: I just saw the rules, It never mentioned if they want multiple spaces or just one space. If I want only 1 space, what should I do to change this?

Comment: @Ronald Use `^\d+[0-9| -]\d+$`, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/t0SHfh/3)

Comment: For only one space: `"34343-1232".matches("^[0-9|-]*[0-9| -]+[0-9|-]*$")`

Comment: @user10340091 No need to make the pattern more complicated that it needs to be. `^\d+[0-9| -]\d+$` will work fine for OP requirements.

Comment: As he is matching zip codes, he is probably just matching digits separated by a delimiter.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yours specifies that it must start and end with one or more digits, and contain at least one of `[0-9| -]`. So "1" would not match and "12" would not match. Which usually aren't valid zip codes, but I'm being pedantic to what OP says

Comment: Yeah, that's true :) But `^[0-9|-]*[0-9| -]+[0-9|-]*$` is wrong, it matches empty strings, `1111111111` and `----------`

Comment: REs like this are very irresponsible. This RE would allow `-` or `---------------------------------------`. While its working from incomplete information (only one example from the question), https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285067/3917091 is more responsible. If you're invoking regex to validate the format, you should do it properly.

Comment: `^[0-9|-]*[0-9| -]+[0-9|-]*$` does not match empty strings