# php - check if an address string has a zipcode

Tags: php, regex, zipcode

I'm trying to use regex to check if a full address string contains a zipcode, can someone help me out?

```
$address = '10100 Trinity Parkway, 5th Floor Stockton, CA 95219';
if (preg_match('--regex_here--',$ad)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: is the zip code going to be a separate string from the address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally zip codes follow the two letter state code, so something like the following should be fairly reliable:

```
/\b[A-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b/
```

Explanation:

```
\b         # word boundary
[A-Z]{2}   # two letter state code
\s+        # whitespace
\d{5}      # five digit zip
(-\d{4})?  # optional zip extension
\b         # word boundary
```

You could also change the `\b` at the end to `$` since zip codes are usually (always?) at the end of the address.

Comment: I didn't think ZIP codes included the state code. I thought it was just the 5 digits or ZIP+4.

Comment: @sachleen - The ZIP code does not include the state code, but if you just checked for five digits you might catch street numbers or apartment numbers.  Adding the state code check is just some extra verification that the number is actually a ZIP code.

Comment: Makes sense. I misunderstood your response the first time. ZIP code just follows the state code, not includes it.