# JavaScript regex to extract digits and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing some JavaScript regex combination. I have a text like this.

```
city, state postal code
```

I want regex code that would separate the parts of text that contains only letters (state) and then put comma after it. The text would separate the postal code which can contain letters and numbers from the state which contains either letters and number or just numbers.

Is there a regex solution for this or can I use something else built in JS?

Edit:

I used this regex:

```
/\d{6}/
```

But this only gets US post codes and I need world wide.

```
Newmanstown, Pennsylvania 17073
morris, Alabama 35116
London , England  EC2R 8AH
```

The last is taken from google.

Comment: what regex have you tried?

Comment: Also, an example of *actual* data would be helpful too. But yes, a solution with regular expressions probably exists. If you don't know regex very well, I recommend to have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: `But this only gets US post codes and I need world wide.` Some country does not use postal code. How is your string going to be like?

Comment: I don't know about those countries. The city and state only have letters so that could be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex), you'll find patterns for some countries. 
But, it will be very difficult to build a completly reliable system who verify postal code for all the countries.