# RegEx for English and Australian Postcode

Tags: php, regex

Could anyone point me in the right direction for a regular expression to validate an English postcode and Australian Postcode

English Eg: AA11 1AA
Australian: 1111

My current expression to validate an English Postcode is:

```
$PostCodeRegex = '~^(GIR 0AA)|(TDCU 1ZZ)|(ASCN 1ZZ)|(BIQQ 1ZZ)|(BBND 1ZZ)'
.'|(FIQQ 1ZZ)|(PCRN 1ZZ)|(STHL 1ZZ)|(SIQQ 1ZZ)|(TKCA 1ZZ)'
. '|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]'
. '|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))'
. '|[0-9][A-HJKS-UW])\s?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$~i';
```

Comment: What is the problem with yours? Matches something it shouldn't? Doesn't match something it should? Please add some samples. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

Comment: Why do you want one regex to do all the work?  What's wrong with two different ones?

Comment: Might be better to have a country select box, then you can have an if statement to check the selected country an test the postcode against the appropriate regex, rather than one to catch both.

Answer (score 2):

You could've google it a bit, I found plenty of answers myself...

I'm not sure about you UK regex above since it doesnt work for me, so I tried this one:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/164992/1519058
```

And googling, I found this regex for australian postecodes:

```
^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$

Source: http://www.etl-tools.com/regular-expressions/is-australian-post-code.html
```

So now you just concatenate both using a "|", and it might gives you what you want:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$|^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$
```

You can try it [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/bT2zA6)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly answering your question as it's stated, but I'd honestly suggest using the [PEAR](http://pear.php.net) [Validate_AU](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_AU)  and [Validate_UK](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_UK) packages instead of utilising a regex that could possibly allow false positives through.