# 6 character long string matching using php regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've the following `string`

```
1=>    Stephen Avenue 700 Center St SE Calgary, AB T2G5P6
```

`2=>    Montgomery 4611 Bowness Rd NW Calgary, AB T3B0S4`

`3=>    Uptown 17th Ave 1022 17 Ave SW Calgary, AB T2T0A5`

and I want to get `T2G5P6` from first, `T3B0S4` from 2nd and `T2T0A5` from 3rd  using `regular expressions` 
Thanks

Comment: That is not a good enough quantifier: `'Avenue'` is also a 6 char string

Comment: what do you want ?? tell me and I will help you

Comment: I want to get `T2G5P6` mean combination of integers and characters.

Comment: @Mubin, ask what you want to achieve in general, not in the particular row of yours.

Comment: @ Rolice,  I get this address string from a page and I want to get the zip code from that

Comment: Is is always preceeded by 2 char string? Is it always upper case?

Comment: Ok, have you tried to search in SO before posting there are a lot of question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529103/825114 - this is with cases for different countries also.

Comment: yes it is always uppercase and followed by two chars.

Comment: @Mubin for starters you can post at least 5-10 sample text and the output you nedd, then only we can help dear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get `T2G5P6` using regular expressions.
Of course you can.

use this regex :

```
/T2G5P6/
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/lY8qS6

on a serious note:

if you say these rules about your pincode

- only six characters
- only capital letters and digits

then this regex will be helpful for you :

```
[A-Z0-9]{6}
```

second demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oA1qL9

Comment: OK, but this is sample query, I mean I want regular expression that could extract this string and same like this string from other strings that I provide to it

Comment: "*same like this string from other strings*" — Without knowing what *you* consider to be "same", we cannot really answer that.

Comment: @Mubin To be honest, aelor did answer your question. If you update it and be a little more specific I'm sure we'll be glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use this `([A-Z0-9]{6})` pattern to get the 6 characters from your string

**Demo**

[**http://regex101.com/r/wY2tZ5**](http://regex101.com/r/wY2tZ5)

Answer (score 0):

If it always going to be LetterDigitLetterDigitLetterDigit you can use

```
([a-zA-Z]\d){3}
```

Comment: buddy a pin code can have any order of chars