# Verifying address using regular expression

Tags: regex, validation

I need to make an expression where there are no white spaces in the beginning, begins with street number that should be at least one digit and at most 4 digits and should end with a postal code of 6 digits. An example would be:

`29 Younge Street M5E 1B2`

I have this `/^[^\s][a-zA-Z\s]+$/` but don't know how to add the extra conditions
Thanks

Comment: Can you control where the data is coming from?  Meaning the way the user is entering it?

Comment: How robust does this have to be?  [As seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex) postal codes can be tricky to validate with regex.  If you just care about one region's, you might specify the criteria they follow.  Also, how many words/characters can the street name be?

Comment: Woul you add examples of what your regex should match. `End with a postal code of 6 digits` is not valid to your example. To fit it it must be `end with a postal code of three chars a space and three chars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your postal code look Canadian to me where the format is `A1B 2C3` and if I recall correctly, Younge Street is a street in Montreal. Your requirements basically boils down to "start with 1 to 4 digits, end with the 6-character postal code". Use this:

```
^\d{1,4}\s+.*[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z]\s*\d[A-Za-z]\d$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bU5oD8/1)