# How can write regex validate for zipcode in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a registration form. I need to validate zipcode. Validation rules must be integer, Max length not greater than 7.

I had tried validation but it validate zip must be 5. But some countries has 6 or 4 zipcode. Any help would be appreciated.

```
'zipcode'   => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{5}(\-[0-9]{4})?$/',
```

Comment: What are a few correct and incorrect zip codes you're looking to validate against?

Comment: What's the minimum length?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, Minimum 3 numbers.

Comment: So an integer between 3 and 7 digits?

Comment: @WildBeard Correct validation: 5432, 54321, 543232, 2345671. Incorrect: #1234, ada12334, 12345678, 0, #

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - won't work. ZIP+4 in the US is 5 digits, a dash, followed by four more digits. The dash is part of the code. You should really look at [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex) to get a better understanding of the scope of this problem. :-)

Comment: @samsam - incorrect. British and Canadian postal codes have letters tossed in. US ZIP codes are *always* five digits - but US ZIP+4 codes are five digits, a dash, and five more digits. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis I am not looking exact zipcode validation. In my case no special characters allowed, minimum any 3 number needed maximum any 7 numbers, integer only.

Comment: Great. BTW - American Samoa uses a postal code formatted as NNNNN-NNNNNN. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is numeric digits only, at least 3 but no more than 7, you should use

```
'zipcode'   => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{3,7}$/'
```