# How do i distinguish between number string and character string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var snumber1 = "123456789";
var scharacter2 = "abcdefgh";
```

there're two strings. how do i make sure snumber1 contains only numbers??
What regex??

Comment: A regex isn't really necessary here, but if you're curious it would be `/^\d+$/` for only numbers, or `/^\d*$/` if you want to match the empty string also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var snumber1 = "123456789";
//built-in function
alert ( !isNaN ( snumber1 ) );
//regexp
alert ( /^[0-9]+$/.test ( snumber1 ) );
//another regexp
alert ( /^\d+$/.test ( snumber1 ) );
//convert to Number object
alert ( parseFloat ( snumber1 ) === Number ( snumber1 ) );
```

Comment: `/[0-9]/` will match any string that has at least one digit.

Comment: what's the difference between !isNaN and isNaN?? Can isNaN be enough??

Comment: Yes, just ask to see if isNaN() is false.

Comment: @isbadawi my bet - I fixed it.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove !isNaN is just to follow the logic of the example - if it`s a number will alert true, if not - false.

Answer (score 2):

The regex to determine if something is just numbers is this:

```
"^\d+$"  or  "^[0-9]+$"
```

Source: [StackOverFlow 273141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only/273144#273144)

Answer (score 1):

You need this function:

```
isNaN(string)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: See the above link: `isNaN("12")` //returns false; `isNaN(12)` //returns false

Comment: @isbadani: how does this help?

Comment: @Jiri `isNaN` does (more or less) the opposite of what the OP wants (the OP needs "is not not a number").

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are unnecessary:

```
var snumber1 = "123456789",
    scharacter2 = "abcdefgh";

if ( isNaN(+snumber1) ) {
  alert('snumber is not a number!');
}

if ( !isNaN(+scharacter2) ) {
  alert('scharacter2 is not a string!');
}
```

Note that I am using the `+` operator to do type coercion. Doing so will always result in a number or NaN. If you use the `parseInt` or `parseFloat` functions you could get '10' from `parseInt('010abc', 10)`. This clearly doesn't pass your test for "only numbers" [(*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Numbers).

Comment: Better yet, considering isNaN has edge cases, use `if(+sNumber1 != +sNumber1)`, which is true iff sNumber1 is not a number.

Comment: @Thaddee: `+sNumber != +sNumber` has *exactly* the same edge cases as `isNaN` with an additional downside that it's quite a bit slower than `isNaN` - believe it or not, `isNaN` performs the same number conversion on the argument passed before checking it.  This also means that the `+` in `isNaN(+str)` is completely unnecessary and just adds extra overhead with no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SWITCH` statements instead of `IF`.

```
var valueA=100

switch(/^[0-9]+$/.test( valueA ))
{
    case false:
        alert ("'" + valueA + "'" + " Is NOT a number.Try Again");
        break;
    case true;
        alert ("you've got numbers")
        break;
}
```

This will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `parseInt`

```
if (parseInt(snumber1) == snumber1){ alert('is a number'); }
```