# How to verify that, using regex, all characters in a string are digits?

Tags: regex

How can I verify that every character in a string is a 0-9 digit?
For example: 1343151234234 is valid but 2342343ABC34234 is not valid.
Thank you.

Comment: in what context are you using the regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 5):

`^\d+$`

Using 'SingleLine' option (in C# it is `RegexOptions.SingleLine`).