# Get a certain String from text

Tags: c#

How do you get this string from this data? (The bolded part is what I want)

```
Id: 20 - Cow Amt: **10**

Id: 25 - Example Amt: **5**
```

I made this code to remove everything else except for the ID number

```
id = id.Replace("Id: ", "")

If (id.ToString.Length > 5) Then
    id = id.Substring(0, id.IndexOf("-") - 1).Trim()
```

But now I want to also get the Amt: number as well.
The outcome of the code so far is this:

> 20

It just prints out the id. But how do you get the 10? So it would look like this:

> 20 10

Comment: what about a simple loop? find where the 'A' of "Amt" is and print from there.

Comment: what's the meaning of `Cow` in this data? Your string doesn't seem to have a specific rule

Comment: I'd recommend going for regular expressions matching only numbers (thus, you'd get 2 matches: 20 and 10; though it may change if your unnecessary text will contain numbers also). Here's SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: Data cow is just an example. I'll take a look for regex.

Comment: the tag and the title a confusing... are you asking for vb.net or c# or don't you care as long as it is in the .net family?

Comment: What the... I never tagged it to be c#. but anyways its fixed and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

> ```
> var subjectString = "Id: 20 - Cow Amt: 10";
>
> string[] values = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\D+");
>
> foreach (string value in values)
> {
>     int number;
>     if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(value);
>     }
> }
> ```

Remeber to include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` in the references at the top