# Validating a numeric textbox

Tags: c#, validation

I'm trying to validate a textbox to check that it has a phone number type value entered.

The problem I'm having is that even when the entry is for example: "blah" in these text boxes the Regex is still returning false and no error message is shown.

```
Regex staffNumVal = new Regex(@"^[a-z]+$");

if (staffNumVal.IsMatch(txtStaffHPhone.Text)||(staffNumVal.IsMatch(txtStaffHourRate.Text)))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be sure there is no whitespace? If your values need trimming or contain whitespace that Regex won't match...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Regex staffNumVal = new Regex(@"^[a-z]+$");
```

Use

```
Regex staffNumVal = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");

if (staffNumVal.IsMatch(txtStaffHPhone.Text)||(staffNumVal.IsMatch(txtStaffHourRate.Text)))
{
  //Valid
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex staffNumVal = new Regex(@"^\d*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(txtStaffHPhone.Text, out value))
{
    // it's a valid integer 
}
```

Comment: if value is grater then int MaxValue, this will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
```

Refer for Details: [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx does not do what you expect it.

I think the '^' is misplaced. It should be: @"[^a-z]+$".

But even that is wrong, since it accepts things like &.

You can test at: http://regexhero.net/tester/

But I think you'll be better served with a MaskedTestBox. Have you tried that?