# The simple regex expression [0-9]* does not work with {e|24} in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I've been working on my own simple Wikipedia parser in C#. So far I'm not getting very far because of this problem.

I extract the string `{e|24}` but it could contain any number. All I want to do is simply extract the number from this string.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
Match num = Regex.Match(exp.Value, "[0-9]*");
Console.WriteLine(num.Value);
```

However `num.Value` is blank.

Can someone please explain why this is not working and how I can fix it?

Comment: This is trivial to test in a tool. I use http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ which will give you exact results for .NET.

Comment: To further explain why this didn't work, [0-9]* actually matches your string in 6 places: `><{e|24}`, `{><e|24}`, `{e><|24}`, `{e|>24<}`, `{e|24><}`, and `{e|24}><`. So it did find the part you wanted, but it also matched 5 empty strings, and Match() only returns the first match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to use [0-9]+ to ensure at least one number. [0-9]* allows it to be matched 0 times or more, thus getting blanks

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, make the regexp: `\d+`

Works. Simpler. Shorter, uses no groups or ranges.

Comment: [0-9] and \d are not the same identifier in .Net, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: Ok, but unless the string is going to contain numerals from other languages (and OP doesn't want to match them), \d should do fine.

Comment: Woah, I did not know that. Thanks for sharing. The more you know.