# regex query implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to check a search box and this is my query which works but has a couple of problems.

```
 // =================================
 var check = new Regex("[^A-Za-z]");
 Match m = check.Match(searchQuery);
 if (m.Equals(check) != true)
 {
     pnl_Message.Visible = true;
     pnl_Message.CssClass = "messageTable";
     lbl_message.Text = " * Only Letters are allowed";
  }
```

The If statement Equals says Suspicious comparison !
 but works!
 the thing is it always goes in the if statement no matter what I set the expression too.

How should I be Querying the searchQuery?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only look at the  "^[0-9]+$" note

Comment: you should check out the class at msdn before you use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Equals` is comparing a `Match` to a `Regex` - they're different classes, so it's never true, and you always go into your `if` block.

You probably want `if (m.Success)` - that checks whether the value returned by `check.Match(...)` was a successful match (i.e. the input contained a non-letter) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Object`'s `Equals` method which is the base class for `Regex`

Use `IsMatch` method of `Regex` class i.e `check.IsMatch(searchQuery)`