# What is the best way to parse this number from the longer string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I have the following example strings

```
"CTS3010 - 6ppl"
```

or

```
"CTs3200 - 14ppl"
```

or

```
 "CTS-500 2ppl"
```

and i need to parse out the number from these strings.  What is the best way to parse out the number before the "ppl"  at the end of the string.  Do i need regex? I have logic to loop backward but it feels like there is a more elegant solution here.

These are just examples but all examples seem to follow the same pattern being

- A bunch of text
- A number
- ppl suffix

Comment: Are these 3 formats the ONLY formats exclusively?

Comment: is your number between - and ppl eg: -NUMBER ppl

Comment: I updated the question to be more explicit

Comment: does bunch of text ends with '-'

Comment: It;d be more helpful if you also supply the out put you'd expect from each input. i.e. for example one do you want 3010 or 30106?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to grab the number right before "ppl":

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9]+)ppl");
string matchedValue = regex.Match("CTS-500 122ppl").Groups[1].Value;
```

In this case `matchedValue` will be 122.

If you want to be safe, and you know "ppl" will always be at the end of the string, I would change the Regex to: `"([0-9]+)ppl$"` (the only difference is the dollar sign at the end).

Comment: Is there any difference between `[0-9]` and `\d`? I see lots of people using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` these days...

Comment: According to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only \d will match non-western numeric characters too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using LINQ:

```
const String ppl = "ppl";
var examples = new[] { "CTS3010 - 6ppl", "CTs3200 - 14ppl", "CTS-500 2ppl" };
var delimiters = new[] { " " };
var result = examples
    .Select(e => e.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(t => t.Last().ToLowerInvariant().Replace(ppl, String.Empty))
    .Select(Int32.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Note that this will fail if it can't parse the integer value. If you can't guarantee each string will end with `NNppl` you'll need to check that it is a numeric value first.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about the "best way" but one method that is very easy to understand and modify is an extension method for a string object:

```
 public static int Parse(this string phrase)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phrase)) { throw new NullReferenceException("phrase is null");}

        string num = string.Empty;
        foreach (char c in phrase.Trim().ToCharArray()) {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) { break; }
            if (char.IsDigit(c)) { num += c.ToString(); }
        }
        return int.Parse(num);
    }
```

Assumes " " is the break condition. You may prefer int.TryParse if there is some chance you don't get a number and/or maybe a System.Text.StringBuilder.