# unity regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

Hello I am using the following regex command to only allow numbers be inputted into a text field

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
```

however this obviously doesnt allow the inputting of positive and negative signs +/-. I would like to be able to input -9 for a negative value but when i do it comes back as 09 instead. Any help in getting the regular expression right would be appreciated.

Comment: how about `[+-]?\d+` ?

Comment: unfortunatel that doesnt work in unity c# scripts but thanks for the help

Comment: It may be good idea to show a bit more code - your regular expression disallows one digit, so it is not very clear what exactly you are trying to validate this way.

Comment: @AlanFletcher - it was more an idea about how to approach the problem. Someone answered below with something that has exactly the same semantics.

Comment: initVel1 = rgx.Replace(initVel1, "0"); that is where i call it to replace text values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 4):

There you go, this one works 100% just tested to make sure ;)

```
Regex r = new Regex("^([-+]?)?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$");
```

Comment: Regex rgx = new Regex("[^-][^0-9]+"); it does work but weirdly for exactly what im trying to do, the code i entered here works best for me.  thnk you for all your help and time. its appreciated

Comment: The one you have written should NOT work as a regular expression in C# with the input '[^-]' it allows every character but the minus...

Answer (score 0):

Your expression resolves to *everything except 0 to 9* in my view... To allow *any number with positive or negative sign* I would use the following expression:

```
([-+]{0,1}[0-9]+)
```

+ or - at the beginning 0 or 1 times, and any quantity>0 of 0...9 after.

Answer (score 0):

Regex rgx = new Regex("[^-][^0-9]+");