# check the string having full number or the combinbation of number and string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check whether a string is only numeric, or is alphanumeric.

For example :

```
string test = "2323212343243423333";
string test1 = "34323df23233232323e";
```

I want to check test having number only or not. If the whole string having number means it returns true. Otherwise it returns false.

How can i do this?

Comment: `test1` is a valid hexadecimal number.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: Have you googled **`check whether a string is only numeric`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the string length is not too long, you may try `int.TryParse(string here)` or you may write the function yourself by checking every character in the string like

```
if(MyString[i]-'0'<= 9 && MyString[i]-'0'>= 0)
//then it's a digit, and check other characters this way
```

Comment: The example the OP gives is definitely too long for int.TryParse()

Comment: yeah, I've made it clear I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool allDigits = text.All(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Or

```
bool allDigits = text.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Unless by "numeric" you include hex numbers? My answer only works for strings that contain only digits, of course.