# how to extract characters until find a numeric in sub-string in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to extract characters until find a number in substring in asp.net c#

my string is like

NR21380
SR9956
NER6754
WR98765
SR98700

Comment: Where is your code showing your effort? What is expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 15):

One easy way:

```
var firstLetterCharacters = text.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter);
```

or the other way around:

```
var firstLetterCharacters = text.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c));
```

If you need a new string from it:

```
string newText = new string(firstLetterCharacters.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to replace all non-letters:

```
string s=NR21380 SR9956 NER6754 WR98765 SR98700
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just try to guess the output:

```
string s = "NR21380 SR9956 NER6754 WR98765 SR98700";
var list = s.Split()
            .Select(x => String.Join("", x.TakeWhile(c => char.IsLetter(c))))
            .ToList();
```

Output will be list of `NR SR NER WR SR`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   String aa = "NR21380 SR9956 NER6754 WR98765 SR98700";
    //getting the first chars from the dummy string.
    var firstChars= Regex.Match(aa, @"[A-Z]+");
```