# String checking with Regex

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, string, textbox

I have a `textBox` in my program that contains a `string` that has to meet a few requirements. I'm asking this question to figure out the best way to meet these requirements.

This `string` can't be `NullOrEmpty` and it must be completely composed of integers. The `string` can also contain spaces, which is my sticking point because spaces aren't integers.

This is what I'm working with (I'm aware that it may be a bit redundant at the moment):

```
//I test the string whenever the textBox loses focus
private void messageBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
          ButtonEnabled = true;
      else if (Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, @"^\d+$") == false)
      {
          //I think my problem is here, the second part of the if statement doesn't
          //really seem to work because it accepts characters if there is a space
          //in the string.
          if (TextBox.Text.Contains(" ") && !Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, @"^\d+$"))
              ButtonEnabled = true;

          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Illegal character in list.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
              ButtonEnabled = false;
          }
      }
      else 
          ButtonEnabled = true;
}
```

I got the `Regex` solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only).

**Question:** How do I make it so that this `textBox` only accepts values like these:
"345 78" or "456"?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If the user type a string like "1 12 13 14", do you need to handle them separately (1, 12, 13, 14) or do you want to read it as one value 1121314?

Comment: @Odrai I'm going to go with handling them separately.

Comment: @gleng I updated my question, hope it helps.

Comment: Build and test your regular expressions here http://regexpal.com/ and try this expression...this should get you started: ^[\d\W]*$

Comment: Here's another online regex tester. It even helps with sample queries: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression seems simple enough. It could be something along the line of (with the specified constraints):

```
^([\s\d]+)?$
```

In your `LostFocus` handler, you could use something like this:

```
ButtonEnabled = Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, @"^([\s\d]+)?$");
```

The button will be enabled if:

1. It's an empty string
2. It contains only digits and spaces

If you want a regular expression that will extract the numbers as well, you could change the pattern to:

```
^(\s*(?<number>\d+)\s*)*$
```

And use the `number` capture group.

Note that the first pattern will match strings that are composed of spaces only.