# android regex non-numbers only

Tags: android, regex, match

I need a regular expression to match a string that is **not** a string of numbers. Given my limited knowledge about regexes, I assume that `.*` means any number of characters that matches the following reg expressions.

Therefore, I thought this would work:

```
.*[\\D]
```

But unfortunately it didn't. Instead this works:

```
.*[\\D].*
```

Can anyone explain to me or at least point to me where i can understand this? The java website and most website that I found is not simple enough.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dP5sC8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point '.' means everything, this could be a number, or any character or symbol. The star '*' indicates the amount, it means it can appear as much as it wants, zero till infinity. The '\D' means a non number.
So in your first regex, the string has to end with a non number.

```
123blablub -> match
blablub123 -> no match
```

In your second regex the non digit is followed by any character which appears zero or more times. In words: your second regex matches with every string that includes one or more non digits.

```
123blablub -> match
blablub123 -> match
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches any character.

`*` is a quantifier that matches the previous token any number of times, including 0.

Therefore `.*` matches any number of any characters.

`[]` denotes a character class. Any character in the class is allowed. For example, `[abc]` matches `a` or `b` or `c` once.

`\D` is a character class of non-digits. (You need to escape the `\` as it is also a special character in Java string literals.) You can combine character classes in character classes so `[\D]` is valid, though it's shorter to write it as just `\D`.

Essentially what the regex you have is: begin with any number of any characters, followed by one non-digit, followed by any number of any characters. That's essentially the same as saying there must be at least one non-digit.