# How to validate only number in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to validate for numbers without using keypress option
why isnt `Char.IsNumber` or `.IsDigit` working
or should I use regex expression for validation

```
private bool ValidateContact()
{
    if (Char.IsNumber(textBox4.Text)){
        return true;
}
```

Comment: because `Char.IsDigit` needs a char not a string

Comment: return Int.TryParse(textbox4.Text, out t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply parse the number:

```
private bool ValidateContact()
{
    int val;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out val))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You are trying to call a method that is written for `char` for `string`. You have to do them all separately, or use a method that is much easier to use, like the above code.

Comment: Your solution will give an error. `Not all code paths return a value`

Comment: But what if user wants to enter an decimal number?

Comment: Then this won't work, try to use `decimal.TryParse` then. The original code from OP doesn't seem to need that, so I left that out. (Contract numbers usually don't have decimals)

Comment: @skates008: Need more help?

Comment: @skates008: please don't forget to mark your question answered if it was.

Answer (score 3):

> why isnt Char.IsNumber or .IsDigit working

because [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wants a `char` not a `string`. So you could check all characters:

```
private bool ValidateContact()
{
    return textBox4.Text.All(Char.IsDigit);
}
```

or - better because `IsDigit` [includes unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063436/284240) - use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
private bool ValidateContact()
{
    int i;
    return int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out i);
}
```

Comment: I personally don't rely on this solution. `char.IsDigit` returns true for all unicode digits.it seems `int.TryParse` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Selman22: good point. I've edited my answer accordingly and included [a link to my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22063436/284240) which was related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string as:

```
private bool ValidateContact()
{
    int n;
    return int.TryParse(textbox4.Text, out n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as documented here http://codepoint.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/numeric-only-text-box-in-net-winforms/ :-

We can create Numeric only text boxes in .Net Windows forms application with adding below code in Key Press Event.

Numeric only text boxes

```
private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse("123", out n);
```

Not `Char.IsNumber()` as that only tests a character.

Answer (score 0):

Try supress every key but numeric or decimal point on textbox.KeyPress

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }

  // only allow one decimal point
  if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Why controlling on keypress ?

Because alerting user after he enters a value is not a efficent way to get input from user.
Instead of doing this , you can prevent user from entering non/valid values when user typing.

Based on Matt Hamilton's Ansver on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers) Question

Comment: Question states 'without using keypress option'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression too.

```
 if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("[^0-9]", textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
            textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
        }
```

Also you can check, textbox only allow numeric value :

[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)