# C# How do I add the Value of a Dictionary to a variable based on its Key?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, console-application

I have to calculate the price of an order based on the input from the user using a Dictionary, but I can't seem to get it right.

1. Chicken Strips - $3.50
2. French Fries - $2.50
3. Hamburger - $4.00
4. Hotdog - $3.50
5. Large Drink - $1.75
6. Medium Drink - $1.50
7. Milk Shake - $2.25
8. Salad - $3.75
9. Small Drink - $1.25

For example, if the input is 236, the price of the order should be $8.

Converting my LINQ query to double didn't work (my query is also definitely wrong).
I don't really know any LINQ but as you can't really use a for loop for a dictionary as they aren't indexed, I don't really have any other choice.

```
        Dictionary<int, double> items = new Dictionary<int, double>()
        {
            { 1, 3.50 },
            { 2, 2.50 },
            { 3, 4.00 },
            { 4, 3.50 },
            { 5, 1.75 },
            { 6, 1.50 },
            { 7, 2.25 },
            { 8, 3.75 },
            { 9, 1.25 }
        };

        string order = Console.ReadLine();
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < order.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(items.Where(x => x.Key == int.Parse(order[i].ToString())).Select(x => x.Value));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Well, the output should be the correct amount of dollars based on the input from the user.

Comment: `sum += items[order[i]-'0'];` ?

Comment: Seriously it was this simple? Can you elaborate on the -'0' part? I don't understand.

Comment: `double sum = order.Sum(ch => items[ch-'0']);` - the `Select` returns each (ASCII) character from the input `order` string, they run from bytes with values 48-57 (where 48 is `0`) so subtract the base value `0` to get a number from 1 - 9. Note that this assumes an ASCII/similar character set where the digits are sequential and ascending. You could use `order.Where(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch))`... to ignore bad characters.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a loop.

```
var sum = order.Sum(c => items[int.Parse(c.ToString())]);
```

Comment: Why use `Select().Sum()` when you can use `Sum(c => )`?

Comment: ^ True, it works with just Sum() in the beginning without using Select() at all.
So the final solution I like the most is: 

double sum = order.Sum(x => items[int.Parse(x.ToString())]);

Comment: @NetMage noted!

Answer (score 2):

This implementation is quite fragile, it only allows 10 items and relies on string parsing but I think the following code does what you're asking:

```
order.Sum(character =>
{
    int id = character - '0';

    return items.TryGetValue(id, out double price) ? price : 0d;
});
```

`TryGetValue` checks that `order` only contains digits which are keys in the items dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
order.Select(c => (c - '0')).Where(c => c > 0 && c < 10).Sum(c => items[c])
```

Comment: Suggest using `Char.IsDigit` before converting to numeric. Also then just use `Sum(c => items[c-'0'])`, no need for `Select` twice.

Comment: @NetMage `IsDigit` is [a bit broader](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) than [0-9] and would require [proper conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063436/why-char-isdigit-returns-true-for-chars-which-cant-be-parsed-to-int) using `char.GetNumericValue()`. But indeed it would be cool as homework :)

Comment: @NetMage You are right about unnecessary last Select, I fix my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum += items[order[i]-'0'];` in your for loop.

This works because '0' is stored with the value 48 (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp)). The rest of the digits are stored in order ('1' is 49, '2' is 50, etc), so '1' - '0' == 1 and so forth.

Comment: I guess you need that second sentence as a comment in your code too though, to understand what it's doing. I'd stick with `int.Parse`any day.

Comment: Maybe it's my background with C/C++, but I feel like every programmer should know  that much about character encodings, at least.