# JavaScript Regular expression to test input string is between 1-10 chars with no whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate user input to return valid if and only if a input string is between 1-10 chars in length and contains no whitespace or non a-z chars.

I'm using this regular expression

```
var re = /(\S[a-z]){1,10}/;
```

but this returns true when numbers are input. And if white space if input e.g

`1`    returns valid.
`a a`  returns valid.

I want to restrict the input to only between l-10(amount) of letters(lowercase)
What I have so far;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ILKkz

Comment: Use __anchors__. `^` and `$`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: "no whitespace or non a-z chars" so... just a-z, then?!

Comment: It is unclear what you want to match. Only digit/number characters? Only a-z characters? Give examples of what you want to be valid and invalid.

Comment: edited. So "a" is valid, "a1" is invalid, "abcdefjklj" valid, "abcdefjkljz" invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [following expression](http://regex101.com/r/aU7pU2):

```
var re = /^[a-z]{1,10}$/;
```

This will anchor your match to the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of your string.  Also, if you just want to allow lowercase letters, all you need is the `[a-z]` and nothing like `\S`.  However, if you want to allow anything but whitespace you would use `^\S{1,10}$`.