# I need a regular expression to match <10, >=20 etc

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, a comparison operator followed by (an optional space and) a number. Decimal points are allowed. This is what I got but it doesn't seem to work.

```
^(>|>=|<|<=|=|==|!=|<>)[.0-9]+$
```

So, examples that should match:

- >9
- <=10
- != 20.0

etc

Examples that should NOT match:

- >>2
- <
- =20.

etc

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
^(>|>=|<|<=|=|==|!=|<>){1}\s?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

**explanation**

`(>|>=|<|<=|=|==|!=|<>){1}` <-- match one of this signs

`[0-9]+`<-- one or more numbers

`([.][0-9]+)?` <-- zero or more occurence of . plus numbers

I don't use `\d` because match `[0-9]` and other digit characters like the Eastern Arabic numerals

Comment: Thanks a ton. Slight edit to your regex:
`([.][0-9]+)?$`
So as not to end by decimal

Comment: op wants an optional space.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

(((<|>)=?)|(!=))\s?\d+(.\d+)?

http://regex101.com/r/pT6xK6/2

Cheers!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a million. But you should include options for == and = signs.

Comment: attention with `\d` that match `[0-9]` and other digit characters like the Eastern Arabic numerals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to match a comparison operator followed by (an optional space and) a number,

```
^(?:>|>=|<|<=|=|==|!=|<>)\s?[0-9]+[.]?(?:[0-9]+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yK8xI1/13)

You are so close. You need to make the capturing group into non-capturing group and also you have to add the pattern for optional space ie,`\s?`

Comment: your regex may also match some invalid data like: =2...3