# Delete a row in a csv if a value in a certain column is not an integer with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, row

I have a csv file with ID numbers and want to delete a row if that ID is not completely a number.

Example:

0001, jeff, smith

0abc, john, jones

I would like the "0abc, john, jones" row removed from the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just had that in your text file and nothing else this would work

```
Import-Csv -path c:\temp\data.csv -Header ID,First,Last | 
    Where-Object{$_.ID -match '^\d+$'} | 
    Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\newfile.csv
```

If you have issue with this please look at the following references

- [`Import-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx)
- [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee177028.aspx)
- [`Export-CSV`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)
- [Regex for numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)