# Validating that the user does not enter a decimal in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

```
if (double.TryParse(txtDays.Text, out days) == false)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Enter a whole number for days.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   txtDays.Focus();
   return;
}
```

I'm a newbie at C# so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is your question exactly? You said `decimal` in your title but parsed `double` in your example. And just `if (decimal.TryParse(txtDays.Text, out days))` would seems better..

Comment: How about using a numeric up/down control rather than a textbox?

Comment: Also, if you want to ensure whole values only and want to continue using a textbox, why not use `if(!int.TryParse(...)`?

Comment: Seconding @TrevorPilley comment. Why not just use an `int` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You want to prevent that the user enters a decimal-separator?  So he is allowed to use  integers only? Then don't try to parse to `double` but to `int`:

```
if (!int.TryParse(txtDays.Text.Trim(), out days))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Enter a whole number for days.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   txtDays.Focus();
   return;
}
```

Maybe it's even better to use [`uint.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kadka85s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since that prevents the `-` sign, but that depends on if negative days are possible.

But you should consider to use the [`NumericUpDown`-control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches and all are covered here:
[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Most common approach is to use a `NumericUpDown` control rather than a `TextBox`.

If you want a message box, Tim's answer is pretty much exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You would be better to use a regular expression to check for this I suspect. 
The following code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
```

will check that the string is an integer, well actually it checks that a single digit is an integer, the link below shows how to amend it to check a full string.

(The code comes from this question: [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only))

Comment: Regex for decimal parsing? o.O

Comment: @SonerGönül, no to confirm that what is entered is an integer not a decimal as per his "Validate user does not enter a decimal". If it passes the regex then it is valid, else it's not.