# Regex to validate a .NET's non-negative decimal or blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, decimal

I'm looking for a regular expression that would validate a non-negative [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) (.NET type), i.e. if a non-negative value can be parsed using `decimal.Parse(...)`, it should be considered valid. Otherwise invalid.

I'm okay if it fails the 28-29 significant digits validation - relying on user's sanity here - and then we have another validation layer that would catch it anyway.

Here is what I came up with:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Problem is that it rejects `1.` which is a valid number (you can verify from the immediate window in VS). Could be other edge cases I did not test. Please advise.

P.S. I included ASP.NET and C# tags because this is for a web application written in C#, in which this regular expression is passed to a 3rd party component, which then works on the client (i.e. JS), so I cannot easily put custom code there (i.e. `decimal.TryParse` or smth like that).

Comment: `decimal.Parse` also accepts a leading sign. `"+1"` is a non-negative value that can be parsed. So is `"-0"`, even. `decimal.Parse` also accepts thousands separators: `"1,000"` can be parsed. `decimal.Parse` is culture-sensitive, so `.` shouldn't be hard-coded unless the culture is as well. `decimal.Parse` accepts whitespace. `" 100 "` can be parsed. There's probably more that I missed.

Comment: @hvd, yes I understand, thank you for mentioning those edge cases. I don't seek to be 100% perfect, just trying to cover 99.9% of test cases. There is also training to ensure that people don't go crazy on the UI. I'm sure it's always possible to break any program, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @hvd, btw +1 test case is handled by the accepted answer.

Comment: As long as you're aware of those edge cases and make a conscious decision not to support them, that's just fine. As long as you accept only a strict subset of what `decimal.Parse` accepts, it should be impossible to slip something by that then breaks your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex based on a negative lookahead to avoid matching single dot:

```
^(?!\D+$)\+?\d*?(?:\.\d*)?$
```

- `(?!\D+$)` is negative lookahead to assert failure when input is non digit characters
- `?:\.\d*)?` allows for matching `123.` type of number.

[RegEx Demo 1](http://fiddle.re/ea0vva)

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/iB1hM8/3)

Comment: Thanks - basic test cases seem to work fine. Could you please also add support for leading zeroes, like 001, and for cases when plus sign is explicitly specified, like +100 ?

Comment: Correction - it accepts a bare + sign, which obviously is not a number.

Comment: Yes use: [`^(?!\D+$)\+?\d*?(?:\.\d*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/iB1hM8/3)

Comment: Ok, perfect. Accepting - please don't forget to update your answer with latest regex and link to regex101.com - it really helps validate common edge cases.

Comment: When testing .NET regexes, it is best to test at .NET dedicated testers. Regex101 does not support .NET syntax. Note that in .NET regex, `\d` does not equal `[0-9]` (see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/273144/3832970)). Do not forget to use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag to make `\d` match the same digits as in JavaScript.

Comment: Fair point Wiktor. I thought http://www.regexplanet.com/ is .NET compliant regex tester that I had in my first demo