# Issue with Validating Phone number on user input,Int to large c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Overview of Project:**

I am creating a multi form application, which consist of two forms and one parent class. Both `Forms` have a series of validation functions, such as `isLetter()` `isNumber()` and `isValidEmail()`. My Issue comes when using the `isNumber()` Function.

```
public static bool numValidation(string strNum)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strNum))
            {
                int temp;
                if (int.TryParse(strNum, out temp))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone Number is a valid input: " + temp);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                { Console.WriteLine(temp + "Is not Valid input!!"); }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

At first glance it works fine but once I tried to break it, I realised that when an actual phone number is entered I get an error saying that the number is too high. Any ideas how to get round this constraint ? as the only reason I need this validation is for phone numbers, Fax etc. I simply need this function to accept very large numbers such as phone numbers

Comment: Parsing something what is not `int` to `int` is as wrong, as a converting `int` to `string` and checking its length to see if the number is bigger than `99`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you use a regular expresion to validate the input in your case

```
public static bool numValidation(string strNum)
{

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");

    return (regex.IsMatch(strNum)) ;
}
```

Parsing a string and not using that value is not really needed.

For more details checkout this answers - [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: cheers. I was using a similar method to this prior, I will implement it and get back to you with my results,+1for me though

Answer (score 2):

From Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez answer

> I suggest that you use a regular expresion to validate the
>   input in your case
>
> public static bool numValidation(string strNum) {
>
> ```
> Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
>
> return (regex.IsMatch(strNum)) ; } Parsing a string and not using that value is not really needed.
> ```
>
> For more details checkout this answers - Regex for numbers only

You could enhance the expression to check the length of the number:

Between 5 and 10 digits:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\d]{5,10}+$");
```

Max 10 digits:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\d]{10}+$");
```

At least 5 digits:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\d]{5,}+$");
```