# How to disable enter alphabet symbols in Combobox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a `ComboBox` element in a windows form. It loads a default collection. 
The user can enter any value manually. How can I prevent the user from entering alphabetical characters?

I want to allow only numeric input, or disable this option altogether.

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried? SO is good at helping you break through technical challenges. It's not really set up well to give you tutorials on things, though, because it's more of a Q&A structure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use Regex As an example
In Combobox_TextChanged event if charcter match remove it

```
 private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    string rex=comboBox1.Text;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");


    if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
    { 
      rex= Regex.Replace(rex, @"(?<=\d),(?=\d)|[.]+(?=,)[A-Z]", "");
    }
    comboBox1.Text=rex;
  }
```

This can help you. [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question (shows how to check a string but not anything relating to the winforms question of how to prevent entering anything in the combobox)

Comment: When to do that? in whicj one event?

Comment: What does do second reg express?

Comment: it removes the characters

Comment: How is `(?<=\d),(?=\d)|[.]+(?=,)[A-Z]` remotely close to what OP asked?

Answer (score 1):

> allow only numbers

In fact, you don't need regex for this simple requirement.

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text.Any(x => !char.IsDigit(x)))
    {
        comboBox1.Text = string.Concat(comboBox1.Text.Where(char.IsDigit));
        comboBox1.Select(comboBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

You may also want to add a `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();`