# ASP.NET Routing - adding number as constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add number/int as constraint in route.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Product",
        "{ProductName}/{ProductId}",
        "~/Product.aspx",
        false,
        new RouteValueDictionary 
            {{"ProductName", "[a-z]"},{"ProductId", @"^\d+$"}}
       );
}
```

This is ok: **example.com/productX/1234**

But it is opening Product.aspx even if {ProductId} is not number/int.

So I don't want to **example.com/productY/xyz** route to Product.aspx. What is wrong with that route?

Second question, {ProductName} can have letters, digits and dash(-) in it, how to change {ProductName} regular expression to target all letters, numbers, and dash(-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using the wrong [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute(v=vs.110).aspx) for setting your constraints. You are trying to set `defaults` rather than `constraints`. This should work:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Product",
    "{ProductName}/{ProductId}",
    "~/Product.aspx",
    false,
    null,
    new RouteValueDictionary 
        {{"ProductName", "[a-z]"},{"ProductId", @"^\d+$"}}
);
```

Notice the `null` for the `defaults` parameter.

As for the `ProductName` constraint, you can use `@"^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$"`. Your final code becomes:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Product",
    "{ProductName}/{ProductId}",
    "~/Product.aspx",
    false,
    null,
    new RouteValueDictionary 
        {{"ProductName", @"^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$"},{"ProductId", @"^\d+$"}}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

About your 1st question look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/273144

And 2nd: try `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$"`