# How to grab only number from a Text in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Within a foreach loop I am capturing a piece of text of the element if it is displayed. However I only want to grab the number within the element text (both positive and negative).

Currently the text can read either:

```
+156 on same day
or
-88 on same day
```

I want to only grab the values from this text so this should either be:

```
156
or
-88
```

How can I grab only the numbers and if minus number the negative symbol from the alternativeAirportPrice.Text?

```
public string GetAlternativeAirportPrice(By airportPriceLocator)
{
    var alternativeAirportPrices = _driver.FindElements(airportPriceLocator);

    foreach (var alternativeAirportPrice in alternativeAirportPrices)
    {
        if (alternativeAirportPrice.Displayed)
            return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: there are numerous ways to do this.. but you could use some of the built in extension methods such as `Char.IsNumeric` do a quick google search for examples online

Comment: This isn't so much a selenium question as much as it is a string parsing question. Searching for that might help in your research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: Ues regluar expression can make your code look simple.  Try ([+-]\d+) in your code,  I'm not C# fans, But i try it on browser console, like ('+156 on same day').match(/([+-]\d+)/)[1] ,  browser console use JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that code:

```
string test = "-123";
string result;
foreach(Char i in test) {
    if (Char.IsNumber(i)) {
        result += i;
    }
}
int value = int.Parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need number as int instead of your line:

```
return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
```

you can write:

```
    int r;
    int.TryParse(alternativeAirportPrice.Text.Trim().Split(' ').First(), out r);
    return r;
```

It will work for both cases you've written. If there could be empty string, you can check for empty string before calling string methods. If you might have decimal number - just change int to double. 
But of cause you gotta change your method return type to int.