# Regex match for match of 3 alphabets followed any number of digits

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a sequence of alphabets and any number of digits seperated by a '-' . For example `ABC-1`, `ABC-12`, `ABC-123`, `ABC-1234` and so on..... I looked at an example [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx .I got a code below.

```
var regex = new Regex($@"^[A - Z]{{{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}}}-\d+");
return regex.IsMatch(stringToMatch);
```

where `numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen = 3` but it always return false for the above examples. Please point out where the mistake lies, which will help me to accomplish my goal. Thank you all

Comment: Drop *spaces* in the pattern: `...[A-Z]...`

Comment: [A-Z] not [A - Z]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are *meaningful* in the pattern, that's why in your current code

```
 ... Regex($@"^[A - Z]...");
```

means in a *range from space to space*. Drop spaces:

```
 var regex = new Regex($@"^[A-Z]{{{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}}}-[0-9]+");
 ...
```

**P.S.** `[0-9]`: in .Net `\d` means *any* unicode digit, e.g. Persian one (`۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹`); I've put `[0-9]` in order to exclude them. You may want to add yet *another anchor*: `$` (in case the *entire string* should match the pattern):

```
 var regex = new Regex($@"^[A-Z]{{{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}}}-[0-9]+$");
 ...
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of the unicode implications of \d in C#. Everyday something new, thanks Dmitry! +1