# Regex split correctly

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string that contains numbers and other characters like: `123\n456? * ,, ;;; '' 333\n789/\\+-` and I'm trying to get only the numbers from it as array like

```
123
456
333
789
```

I've tried something like

```
serials = Regex.Replace(serials, @"\r\n?|\n|\t", " ");

var serialNumbers = Regex.Split(serials, @"(?<!($|[^\\])(\\\\)*?\\);");
```

but my array has something like

```
123 456? * ,, 
empty
empty
 '' 333 789/\\+-
```

Is there a way to split this string correctly?

Comment: maybe helpful and the right path for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/273144/3225

Comment: Why don't you just match with `\d+`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try *matching*, not *splitting* (i.e. *extracting* numbers from the string):

```
 string[] numbers = Regex
   .Matches(source, "[0-9]+")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .ToArray();
```

If you insist on splitting it can be

```
 string[] numbers = Regex
   .Split(source, "[^0-9]+");
```

which is more compact, but, probably, less readable.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for your response! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
int[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+")
            .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
```

if you want them like strings just remove the line with (int.Parse).
The way it works it is the following:
 Splits the string by digits, then it tries to parse each string from the collection and if it's possible just put the string in the collection, (out _  is C# 7 features you can read more here -> [Discards](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-7-0-and-c-sharp-7-1-new-features-part-two/)) and then if you need to you can parse each string to number and "materialize" them into array you can check here -> [Enumerable.ToArray() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)