# How to set Regex

Tags: c#, .net

There maybe answers already with this i am not sure. but i want to setup my regex in c# to only check for a specific value. i need to understand regex better in c# any readings

I Currently have the following.

```
 string phoneNumberPattern = @"^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$";
 Regex phoneNumberRegex = new Regex(phoneNumberPattern);
```

but i only want it to be true for vaules in the following format.

```
18764329532
+18764329532
```

How do i go about fixing this?

Comment: What's the problem with the current one?

Comment: go to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: Do you want to match (a subset of) phone numbers or numbers? (Your code indicates the former, your text the latter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
^(\+)?\d{11}$
```

### Explanation:

```
^          // should start with
(\+)?      // this makes sure + is at start only once
\d{11}    // followed by 11 digits
$         // end of line
```

See this working [Example DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5c%2b%29%3f%5cd%7b11%7d%24&i=%2b18764329532)