# Trying to find regex for my string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string. Each number is separated by a tab

```
35  64  -33 -39 37  49  41  34
```

I am trying to find a suitable regex expression to match that string so I can use it in my C# program. So far I have tried a few online tools but those tools could not generate it.

What I am trying to achieve is to match

```
56  110 -47 -58 57  73  59  47
```

but not

```
56  110 -47 -58 a   73  59  47
```

EDIT: the regex must match any number. Those are just a few examples from my file. The numbers can be both positive, negative and 0

I am using the regex to validate if a text file is consited only of lines with the above structure (letters only and tabs as separation).

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only?rq=1

Comment: Do you want it to match the numbers in the last example, and just skip the `a`?

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen I do not want to match the line if it has anything but number. It must match the tabs and from 1 to 8 numbers. Also added an edit to my question.

Comment: So it can only be numbers, you want a regex to find letters?  This is a pretty basic usage of regex.  Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Perfect opportunity to advertise this awesome Regex gem: https://regex101.com/

Comment: For c#, try [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester), regex101 does not support C# flavored regex.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma Regex101 is kilometers ahead with regards to user experience, and in most cases the Regex does work in C#. If you need to do something out of the general regex queries (lookahead/behinds and advanced/named grouping), then sure, regexstorm makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(-?((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*))\t)*(-?((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*)))$` If you want to grab the whole string if and only if all the values within are tabbed numbers

`-?((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*))` if you want to grab each individual number in the string

Comment: This matches a lot of invalid numbers, for instance: `3-3` would be valid with this regex.

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen Good point, I've updated the pattern

Comment: Now, it will also match `.............`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the pattern again, please let me know if you see any more mistakes

Comment: Looks like that regex would match 1.    .1    etc, think you're after something like this: 
^(((-?\d+\.\d+)|(-?\d+))\t)*((-?\d+\.\d+)|(-?\d+))$

Comment: @JasperMoneyshot in my opinion, 1. and .1 are valid numbers (the former is just redundant and the latter is shorthand for 0.1)

Comment: I'd somewhat agree with the .1 however the 1. feels to me like it would indicate an invalid entry.