# How to make sure an int doesn't crash an application when answered with a string

Tags: c#

I have a console app with an `int` variable. I need to read input from the user and be sure I can tell the user that they have entered an invalid answer if the input can't convert to an integer value.

How can I do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers");
        var input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var input2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input1 + input2 == 3)
            Console.WriteLine("");
        else if (input1 + input2 == 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("");
        goto Start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `int.TryParse(...)` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, this will allow you to react to the invalid input.

Comment: Also... there are times when `goto` is helpful, but a new programmer should NOT use it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn And this is _not_ one of those times.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, wasn't actually excepting an answer. I will try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToInt32(string)` will throw exceptions, just as you mention, when the input cannot be parsed.

Instead, use `int.TryParse(string, out var result)`.

In your code, it would be

```
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var input1 ||
    !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var input2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter integers.");
    goto Start;
}
```

You can read more about the method in [the .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

*P.s. By the way, you should avoid using goto in your code. But that's another matter.*

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `int.TryParse` (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

It will return `false` if the input is not an integer.

Ex:

```
int num1;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(!int.TryParse(input, out num1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("that's not a valid integer");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use regular expression, `Regex` is best for c# to check number format. look at this:

> [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: int.TryParse is better since you don't need to write your own logic to validate number formats.

Comment: No, Regex is a hammer and not everything is a nail.