# android - Is it possible to change locale of app without altering number format of whole application?

Tags: android, locale, number-formatting

Is there any possible way to change locale of application **without** altering number formatting ?

For instance, I want change locale of app to Arabic/Persian language but keep digits to be in English format (123456...), and not been in Arabic style (۱۲۳۴۵۶...).

**noted:** setting number format for specific string (textview/edittext) will not solve my issue and it is necessary to set number format in one place for the app (like how we set locale).

Comment: You can use regex to solve this problem as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273144/12971639)

Comment: as I noted, this won't help me.
I need to config it in one place in order to affect all classes of project ( esp for libraries which I have no access for modifying them )

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own common text view which extends TextView and implement regex functionality there.