# WPF - Textbox is accepting only Single digit as user input

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

i am working on reading the user input from textbox. Textbox should accept only numeric and it is working fine. but its taking only single digit as the input. if i enter two digit number in textbox, it is assigning the last digit as the value.

Ex : input is 25. value gets assigned from textbox is 5.

How can i assign full number from textbox.

```
 private void Val(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        e.Handled = Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, "[^0-9]+");
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            value = Int32.Parse(e.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"^\d+$"
```

This argument would include multiple digits. If the digits have to be Arabic specific (0-9) this should work`"^[0-9]+$"`

You can read about it more in a previous discussion here [Regex for numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Comment: it is not working. its blank when i enter any numerical value.its not accepting any value.                                              'Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, @"^\d+$");'