# What is the simplest way to get the year in a string?

Tags: c#, string

In the example below, I want to get the string "2023". All the code I wrote for this is below. I think it shouldn't be hard to get the string "2023" like this. What is the simplest way to get the "2023" in the given string?

```
const string raw = @"TAAD, Türkiye Adalet Akademisi'nin 95. Kuruluş Yıl Dönümü Armağanı, y.78, S.179, Temmuz 2023, s.108-157";
var frst = raw.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(x => x.Any(char.IsDigit) && Convert.ToInt32(new string(x.Where(char.IsDigit).Take(4).ToArray())) > 2000);
var scnd = new string(frst?.Where(char.IsDigit).Take(4).ToArray());
if (scnd.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(scnd) > 2000) MessageBox.Show(scnd);
```

Comment: A regular expression that matches for `@"\b2[0-9][0-9][0-9]\b"` might be the most readable solution. Note: `\b` means "word boundary". You could replace the second word boundary with `,`, but that depends on how your other records look and whether you prefer to err on the side of false positives or on the side of false negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try regular expressions:

```
var pattern = @"\b(\d{4})\b";
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(raw, pattern))
{
  // do something with match
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\d\d\d\d` and not just `\d{4}`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match 4 digits greater than 2000, you can use:

```
\b[2-9][0-9]{3}\b(?<!2000)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[2-9]` Match a digit 2-9
- `[0-9]{3}` Match 3 digits 0-9
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?<!2000)` Negative lookbehind, assert not 2000 directly to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0hbdl/1)

Note that in C# using `\d` also [matches digits in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273144/5424988).

Comment: Good answer! However, I did not understand the last sentence: *Note that in C# using `\d` also matches digits in other languages.*. It seems the sentence does not express correctly whatever you want to tell.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273144/5424988) for using `\d` instead of `[0-9]` I will add it to the answer for clarity.