# Ignoring the leading space captured in a repeated group?

Tags: c#, regex

The following pattern matches a line that starts with 'v' followed by an arbitrary number of floats:

```
    const RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;

    var regex = new Regex(@"^\s*v((?:\s+)[-+]?\b\d*\.?\d+\b)+$", options);

    const string text = @"
v +0.5 +0.5 +0.5 0.0 1.0 1.0
v +0.5 -0.5 -0.5 1.0 0.0 1.0
v -0.5 +0.5 -0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0
v -0.5 -0.5 +0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0
";

    using var reader = new StringReader(text);

    for (var s = reader.ReadLine(); s != null; s = reader.ReadLine())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            continue;

        var match = regex.Match(s);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"'{capture.Value}'");
            }
        }
    }
```

It works as expected except that it includes the leading space before a number:

```
' +0.5'
' +0.5'
' +0.5'
' 0.0'
' 1.0'
' 1.0'
...
```

**Question:**

How can I ignore the leading space for each captured number?

Comment: Is your filestructure always valid, or are there lines that won't match your desired pattern? Ie, is the is it just about getting out all numbers from a valid file or do you need a validity check and want to ignore invalid lines?

Comment: There shouldn't be wrong content but oneself protecting is always nice to have.

Comment: So what happens if you encounter a line like `v 1.0 xy 1.0` completely ignore it?

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't be valid, actually it's a Wavefront Obj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the regex to match the whitespace chars instead of capturing.

This part `(?:\s+)` is the same as just `\s+` and as you repeat the pattern with 1 or more whitspace chars you can omit the word boundary `\b` at the end.

**Note** that in C# `\d` [can match more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only) than `[0-9]`

```
^\s*v(?:\s+([-+]?\b\d*\.?\d+))+$
```

The line in C# would be:

`var regex = new Regex(@"^\s*v(?:\s+([-+]?\b\d*\.?\d+))+$", options);`

Output

```
'+0.5'
'+0.5'
'+0.5'
'0.0'
'1.0'
'1.0'
'+0.5'
'-0.5'
'-0.5'
'1.0'
'0.0'
'1.0'
'-0.5'
'+0.5'
'-0.5'
'1.0'
'1.0'
'0.0'
'-0.5'
'-0.5'
'+0.5'
'0.0'
'0.0'
'0.0'
```

Comment: So basically with your last edit, you removed the last `\b` because it was useless, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You might be overcomplicating this.  I suggest just using the following regex pattern:

```regex
[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Your updated C# code:

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", options);
```

Comment: This won't match the optionally preceding positive and negative signs.

Comment: I am having a bad cold today, mind is not 100% sharp.

Comment: No worries, have some rest so you can come back in shape :)