# How to get numbers after some particular word using regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

Below is my sample text

```
Pick Ticket 81091 Reference 109437
Issuing Date/Time  27/Jan/2022 10:19:10AM Status 35-Pick in Progress
```

I need to get the 6 digits number after this word "Reference". The text will be always like this "Reference ******"

Comment: ```/(Reference)+......[1-9]/g``` should work. It might not be best its just what I know, essentially it finds the group of reference and then gets the next 6 digits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might simply use

```
Reference\s+(\d+)$
```

and use the first capturing group (switch on the multiline modifier).
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wwz3cr/1).

---

In `C#`:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"Reference\s+(\d+)$";
        string input = @"Pick Ticket 81091 Reference 109437
Issuing Date/Time  27/Jan/2022 10:19:10AM Status 35-Pick in Progress
";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea on C#?

Comment: @VignaHariKarthik: Yup.

Comment: Great it worked for me

Comment: can you help me.. this text not able to match                                                        
Pick Ticket 81084 Reference 109430 f O
Issuing Date/Time ~ 27/Jan/2022 10:19:45AM Status 35-Pick

Comment: can you check https://regex101.com/r/GHxyki/1