# I need a regex to invalidate all the same digits in a phone number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

The regex should invalidate the phone number if all the digits are same. For eg - 0000000,1111111,2222222,etc. should be invalid. But on the other hand if I enter 11111112 then this should be valid as it contains another digit as well. The length of the regex should be between 7 to 15.

I tried with this (?!(\d)\1{6})([0-9]{7,15}) but the same is not working as expected. If there is any better way, please suggest me the same.

Comment: I knew someone whose phone number had the same digit repeated throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern at the beginning to assert that there exists at least a digit whose following digit isn't the same:

```
^(?=.*(\d)(?=\d)(?!\1))\d{7,15}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tn9kJd/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single negative lookahead to rule out the same digits 0-9 as in C# using `\d` [could match more digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only) than only 0-9:

```
^(?!([0-9])\1+$)[0-9]{7,15}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `([0-9])\1+$` Capture a digit 0-9 in **group 1** and repeat that same digit using a backreference `\1` one more times till the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[0-9]{7,15}` Match 7-15 digits in the range 0-9
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/roLOfn/1).